# Eurodéputé, MEP, député européen ou membre du parlement européen ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

En Anglais, le terme consacré est MEP. En Français, il y a plusieurs alternatives

- Eurodéputé
- Député européen
- Membre du parlement européen, MPE
- MEP, (en) *Member of the European Parliament*

Entre ces termes, y en a-t-il un plus courant, plus officiel ou plus correct (pour une valeur quelconque de *correct*) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sur [le site web de l'UE](http://europa.eu/about-eu/institutions-bodies/european-parliament/index_fr.htm) ils utilisent :

> ...les membres du Parlement européen (les députés européens) sont…

Le [site wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9put%C3%A9_europ%C3%A9en) (en Français, bien sûr) dit :

> Les termes *eurodéputé*, *MPE* (membre du parlement européen) ou *MEP* (member of the european parliament) sont également utilisés.

Alors encore j'ai essayé de trouver la page d'un MPE [ici](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/fr/search.html). Le résultat ? Le titre dit « députés » !

Alors il semble vraiment que ce soit « MPE » ou « député » (*européen* si le contexte n'est pas clair). « Eurodéputé » n'est pas directement utilisé sur les pages que j'ai vues, mais je soupçonne qu'il le soit également.

Answer (score 1):

*Eurodéputé* ou *député européen* est le plus entendu à mon avis.